# Play and Stop Animation on Condition - Unity

Tags: unity, animation

I've applied a scale animation on Play button of my game. I want to stop animation when play button is not interactable. It stops playing animation, but animation is not playing again, even when play button gets interactable. Here is my snippet to Play and Stop Animation.

```
if (!PlayButton.GetComponent<Button> ().IsInteractable()) {
    PlayButtonAnimator.Stop ();
} else if (PlayButton.GetComponent<Button> ().IsInteractable()) {
    PlayButtonAnimator.Play ("Play_Button_Animation");
}
```

What should i do to play animation again. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the exact answer but instead of doing a `PlayButtonAnimator.Stop()`you could add a `New State` into the animator and call  `PlayButtonAnimator.Play ("New State")` when the button is not insteractable.

```
if (!PlayButton.GetComponent<Button>().IsInteractable())
{
    animator.Play("New State");
}
else if (PlayButton.GetComponent<Button>().IsInteractable())
{
    animator.Play("Play_Button_Animation");
}
```