# Is there a way to start UI animation transition with code in unity?

Tags: unity, animation, gui

I have made an animation for a button in unity's UI prefab, but i want it to start only at certain times, when i command it with code. How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play and Stop Animation on Condition - Unity](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121960/play-and-stop-animation-on-condition-unity)

Comment: @Sam the link gave me the idea bellow. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did this:
The button is for jumping, and as long as you hold your finger on it, it will loop the animation. So in the code where i coded the game to check when the +Y force should be added to the player, i set the button to `button.GetComponent<Button>().interactable =  true;`, and when the force shouldn't be added, to `button.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;`.  For this to work, you should add this to the cs file: `public Transform button;`, and in the editor, add the ui button to the script.